# Silverlight application with WCF

Tags: silverlight, wcf

My requirement is to create a webservice which stores audio and video files into database and I call it in Silverlight application. I'm very new to this field. My problem is I'm able to create the webservice but it's creating a default class like `service1.svc`. I want to create my own class with my own methods to convert audio files into bytes and save it into database. And one more problem is that I want complete coding for how to call webservice methods in Silverlight. And I'm not getting

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
```

in my application.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [WCF RIA services](http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/)

> **WCF RIA Services**
>
> Microsoft WCF RIA Services simplifies
> the traditional n-tier application
> pattern by bringing together the
> ASP.NET and Silverlight platforms. RIA
> Services provides a pattern to write
> application logic that runs on the
> mid-tier and controls access to data
> for queries, changes and custom
> operations. It also provides
> end-to-end support for common tasks
> such as data validation,
> authentication and roles by
> integrating with Silverlight
> components on the client and ASP.NET
> on the mid-tier.

.. From the WCF RIA site

Comment: How does this address Media/bulk uploads?